# FB Login strategy, what to persist?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I've read all the docs, got the code working to authenticate and authorize and post to FB wall, and I'm still confused.

If I use the FB Connect login, I get back an accessToken.  This token is valid for the session, until the user logs out of FB.  So apps that say "login through facebook" must be keeping some kind of info to identify the user.
Do they continually replace/update the access token - that seems to violate the idea that a primary key should not change. 
 Or do they keep a session ID - that seems to have the same problem.

Thanks.

-Mike

Comment: You can use the accessToken to query FB about user info such as facebook id, which will identify the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need the `access_token` for. For example if you are publishing content on behalf of the user, you don't need an `access_token` (or a valid session-online user) at all!

Facebook will check if the user id you are trying to post on his behalf has granted your app the `publish_stream` permission then the process will continue as if the user is logged in.

So basically the user id "**uid**" should be considered a primary key not the `access_token`. Even if you want an `access_token` that will never change or expire (in theory) which you can get using the `offline_access` permission, it's not a good idea to treat it as a primary key.
Not because it may get repeated but it *may* get expired at some rare circumstances.